# Iteratively creating bash shell scripts with change in variables (in Python?)

Tags: python, bash

I am wanting to create a few hundred bash shell scripts where the only difference is the value of a single variable. My script looks something like:

```
~/programs/program -i ~/data/input.NUM -o ~/results/output.NUM
```

where NUM stipulates the input/ output. The only programming language I'm familiar with is python. Is there any way to do this via some sort of for loop for example? I've yet to find a way to even read in bash scripts into python.

Comment: You should create one bash script that takes the varying value as an argument.

Comment: And what do you want to do with all these scripts? If you want the execute them one after another, wouldn't it be easier to have just one bash script, that executes all the commands in one run?

Comment: I'm running these scripts as an array job on an SGE cluster, so I need them to be individual scripts so they can each be run on a single node. I can have the job ID stipulate the input and output, but I still need a way to create all the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your latest comment, I would suggest using a shell loop to create your scripts:

```
for num in {1..100}; do
  printf '~/programs/program -i ~/data/input.%d -o ~/results/output.%d' "$num" "$num" > run"$num".sh
done
```

This creates files like `run1.sh`, `run2.sh`, etc., each with the corresponding number in the input and output.

Comment: This seems great! One last thing, the scripts are more complex than a single line, can I wrap this in more lines of code? i.e. do I have to put all the lines in that single printf or is there a workaround?